# How to show two figures for every x in matplotlib boxplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I'm trying to show two figures for every `x` in my boxplot next to each other. But my code keeps the figures on top of each other. I cannot figure out how to fix this because I'm using three different separated data-frames (`org_data`, `holiday_false` and `holiday_true`). Please help.

`data.csv:`

```
weekday | holiday | casual | registered
---------------------------------------
   0         1        500       153
   2         0        412       654
   6         1        846       113
   2         0        456       121
   3         0        124       654
  ...       ...       ...       ...
  ...       ...       ...       ...
```

`code:`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
plt.style.use('seaborn-notebook')
%matplotlib inline

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 7))
org_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

holiday_false = org_data[(org_data["holiday"] == 0) & (org_data["weekday"] != 0) & (org_data["weekday"] != 6)]
holiday_true = org_data[(org_data["holiday"] == 1) | (org_data["weekday"] == 0) | (org_data["weekday"] == 6)]

ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
sns.boxplot(x=org_data["weekday"], y=holiday_false["casual"], color="orange")
sns.boxplot(x=org_data["weekday"], y=holiday_true["casual"], color="skyblue")
ax1.set_title("Nuber of Casual Users on Holidays and Non-Holidays")
ax1.set_xlabel("Days")
ax1.set_ylabel("Number of Casual Users")

ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
sns.boxplot(x=org_data["weekday"], y=holiday_false["registered"], width=0.50, color="orange")
sns.boxplot(x=org_data["weekday"], y=holiday_true["registered"], width=0.50, color="skyblue")
ax2.set_title("Number of Registered Users on Holidays and Non-Holidays")
ax2.set_xlabel("Days")
ax2.set_ylabel("Number of Registered Users")

plt.show()
```

`the type of chart I get:`

[image]

`the chart I want:`

[image]

Comment: You will need to combine the dataframes into a single one with a new column that says which original dataset the respective datum is part of. Then you can use this new column as the `hue` variable for a single seaborn plot call.

Comment: The example at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py is basically the same layout

Comment: @Reedinationer I have to use BoxPlot

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yeah I don't know how to do that

Comment: Actually, you already have all the data in one dataframe at the beginning. So just don't split them up.

Comment: So how would the syntax look like with the system of "don't split them up"
.

Comment: Could it be that it is not possible to make them side by side?

Comment: No, that could not be. Because in [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) you can see how to plot such graph.

Comment: Yeah I have looked at that numerous times. But I always get errors.

Comment: I cannot workout a correct syntax for this problem